# How do I programmatically alter sort and include columns in the "All Items" view?

Tags: 2007, development, spquery

How to programatically alter existing view "allitems.aspx" aka "All Items" to do an OrderBy (sort by first name and group by department) and only display first, last, m, date of birth, date of hire, last employment date, and department?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: [Changing ListViewWebPart Toolbar and Current View](http://mysharepointstuff.blogspot.com/2009/08/changing-listviewwebpart-toolbar-and.html)

Comment: I can't find your post. Can you please edit this answer with more details? Also please remember to mark questions as answered! Thanks :-)

Comment: The direct URL seems to be http://mysharepointstuff.blogspot.com/2009/08/changing-listviewwebpart-toolbar-and.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which list you're talking about, but if all of those columns are in the list, then you should be able to do this just with the view settings.

Comment: Marc, Yes, bobby is correct. How do i modify existing "All Items" view programatically?

Answer (score 0):

An SPView object has a Query property. Get the all items view, then set the existing Query (for allitems probably empty) to include an OrderBy CAML statement, more on this here:

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/31762/1954